# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x11ad5dbf8> instead of word stems?

Tags: python, nltk, stemming

The following code should output stem words, but instead I get a generator object.

```
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
english_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')

words = ["presumably", "presume", "multiply"]
print(stemmer.stem(w) for w in words)
```

Output:
    generator object genexpr at 0x11ad5df68

This should be really straightforward - what is going wrong?

Comment: Because you created a generator using the generator expression syntax then printed it: `print(stemmer.stem(w) for w in words)` What were you *expecting* to happen? Where did you learn to use that syntax? It sounds like you just want a for-loop: `for w in words: print(stemmer.stem(w))` *not* a generator expression. Although a generator expression looks like shorthand for a for-loop, it is not.

Comment: Or in other terms: use `print([stemmer.stem(w) for w in words])`

Comment: Or `print(*(stemmer.stem(w) for w in words))`

Comment: Haha sorry, where did I learn this syntax? My professor gave it as an example during lecture...but when I tried it at home, it did not work. :( But thank you for your suggestions, it now works!

Comment: Generator expressions (and generators) are a useful construct in general, so you should read about them anyway so that you can use them when you need them :)

Comment: @Mia well, hopefully the target duplicate answers your question, just ask me something if it still isn't clear, but basically, you just want a for-loop.

Comment: @juanpa: I am now trying to apply it to a column within my pandas dataframe, but again I get a lot of generator objects. Could you point me in the right direction? example['col1']=example['col1'].apply(lambda x : (english_stemmer.stem(y) for y in x)).  The output is like this (when printing example['col1'] 1     <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> ...
2     <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> ...
3     <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> ...

Comment: Again, *why are you doing this?* **Dont try to use it unless you know what a generator expression is**.  If you don't want generator objects, then *don't use generator expressions*.

Comment: How else would I stem all the words for each row within a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Mia ... have you looked at the duplicate answer? Have you tried using a for-loop? Or just the equivalent list-comprehension? (although, I would stick to simpler constructs until you have a handle on the basics of the language, learn to walk before you run)

Comment: @juanpa: Yes, I looked at the answer, and yes, I tried a for-loop. I don't get an error but my dataframe does not seem to get populated with the newly stemmed words. :( Shouldn't this do the trick? for row in example['col1']:
    for token in row:
        token = english_stemmer.stem(token)

Comment: No, absolutely not. That's just assigning the result of your stemmer to a variable `token`, overwriting it each time in a loop. You could instead put your for-loop in a function, `def stem_words(words): ...` and use a for-loop to populate a list, then return that list. Then, apply your function. `df['col1'].apply(stem_words)`

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I solved the issue. :)